# Node/Express: How to create a file from a string and stream it to the browser?

Tags: node.js, express

**Trying to:**
1. take a string from the request body and create a file (html file) with this string — *in memory only—no writing to disk*.
2. Send this file (in memory) to the response as a file download.

So far I have...which does not work:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
const {HTMLStr} = req.body;
//HTMLStr is name of form field, contains HTML string

res.set({
 'Content-Type': 'text/html',
 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=myname.html'
});

res.send(HTMLStr);
res.end();
```

I've done something similar in the past where I write an incoming file to disk, read it from disk via `createReadStream` and pipe it to the response—but have never done this without doing the disk write first.

Comment: Try changing the `{HTMLStr}` to `HTMLStr`

Comment: You will need to show more code context so we can see what `req.body` actually is.  Is this a POST handler?  Have you already installed middleware that actually reads the body for you from the incoming stream and parses it? And, does that stream contain JSON with a propery called `HTMLStr`?

Comment: Sending the incoming stream to an outgoing stream is best done with `.pipe()` since both incoming and outgoing are streams.   There are many examples with a web search.  Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472024/simple-node-js-proxy-by-piping-http-server-to-http-request

Comment: No. That's an out of date example. 

The question is `creating a file in memory and streaming it to the client as an attachment`.

The closest example I could find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950049/create-a-text-file-in-node-js-from-a-string-and-stream-it-in-response. Which doesn't really work.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that the incoming response is a stream if you or your middleware haven't already read it.  The outgoing response is a stream.  You can `.pipe()` directly from one to another.  There are literally thousands of examples you can find with Google that do exactly that.   The whole point of piping from one stream to another is to AVOID reading the entire thing into memory as that is not needed.

Comment: If you already have a string that you want to send, then just do `res.send(str)`.  There's nothing more to it than that.   You ignored my first comment about showing use a lot more code context (the whole request/response for both) so we could help more thoroughly so I will leave now.

Comment: "If you already have a string that you want to send, then just do res.send(str)."
Please read more thoroughly. 
HTMLStr is a string. And the example above clearly does just that. `res.send(HTMLStr);`

Comment: Didn’t ignore comment. Please see `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` and comment above. No more context is needed..

Comment: So, then what's the problem?  You're already sending the string you have.  What is the question?  Is the problem that you don't know how to send it as a file downoad?  Is that what this is about?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sessions? If so, you can store the information, if it's not too large, to the session, then retrieve it at anytime.